How to start gparted iso in VirtualBox to resize virtual disk space?
For a Ubuntu 22.04 VirtualBox on windows 10 I wanted to increase the size of the virtual disk space. I saw two similar descriptions HERE and HERE, but when it comes to the part to boot into the gparted iso it does not work. I set up the storage setting as follows

but when I start the VM I always end up in the actual ubuntu 22.04 system, and not in the gparted system.
Any ideas how to fix this, or an easier way to resize the virtual ubuntu disk space?

To resize a virtual disk, you must use the VboxManage tool with the modifyhd option in Virtualbox, as long as the disk is dynamic.

So where can I find a tutorial on how to do these steps, where each step is explained ideally with a screenshot of the tool, function, windows, setting etc to use?

To modify the size of a virtual disk in VirtualBox, use the VBoxManage command. This command must be specified with the parameter modifyhd along with the path to the file and the new size in Mega Bytes.
VBoxManage modifyhd  –resize  -- 8.31. VBoxManage modifymedium

It cannot be done via the GUI? I tried something and I see the "virtual size" is about double the "actual size".  But the "actual size" is still the old one ...
